# Openshift GoLang template error: there is no need to specify a resource, type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form

Tags: windows, go, openshift, command-prompt, go-templates

I have used the below script in command prompt but is throwing error: "there is no need to specify a resource, type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form."

```
  oc get projects -o template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.annotations "openshift.io/description"}}{{end}}
```

[image: This is the screenshot]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to put filter on the display-name column of oc get pods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to use `go-template` to adjust your output, your command needs to looks like follows:

`oc get projects -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{.metadata.annotations "openshift.io/description"}}{{end}}`

There is a good OpenShift blog on how to work with go-templating [here](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/customizing-oc-output-with-go-templates)